# 3d plot of a hyperboloid

Tags: pst-3dplot

I would like to plot the following hyperboloid in 3d. Given the center c = <18,0,0>, principal axis vector v = <-1,0,0>, orthogonal vectors u = <0,1,0>, and w = <0,0,1>, and parameters A = 3, B= 17.748, so that C^2 = A^2 +B^2, and C/A is the eccentricity.  I can express the hyperboloid as follows:

`c + A*sec(x)*v + B*tan(x)*u*cos(y) + B*tan(x)*w*sin(y)`

where `0 <= x < pi/2`, and `0 <= y <= 2*pi`.

I have not been able to get this to work in pstricks format.  The expressions work, because I can plot the hyperboloid in Maple using the above.

Thanks